# Is their a way to conditionally populate a mongoose model

Tags: javascript, mongodb, web, mongoose, backend

I building a simple text app. One of the components in the chat schema is the `chatName`. For a single chat, the chat name takes the id the second user, while for a group chat the chat name is to be entered. Is there I way I can only populate the single chats `chatName` alone with the userName and not disturb the groupChat.

`Below is my chat model`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
 
const chatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    chatName: { type: String, default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    isGroupChat: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    groupAdmin: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    latestMessage: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Message" },
    users: [{ type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
    chatPicture: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", trim: true, default: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQEeF6yBmIjanBabY2MxHEGIt1Oh8ZR1Wo-zXZP4SbQyw&s' },
}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model("Chat", chatSchema)
```

`And in my Controller the fetchChat function`

```
const fetchChat = asyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    var findChat = await Chat.find({
            users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: req.userInfo.id } }
        })
        .populate("latestMessage")
        .populate("users", "-password")
        .populate("groupAdmin", "-password")
        .populate({ path: "chatName", match: { "ChatName": { $ne: "Iroegbu" } }, select: "userName" })
        // .populate({ path: "chatName", match: { isGroupChat: { $eq: true } }, select: "userName" })
        // .populate("chatPicture", "picture")

    findChat = await User.populate(findChat, {
        path: "latestMessage.sender",
        select: "name userName email picture"
    })

    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ nbHit: findChat.length, chat: findChat })

})
```

Is there a way to populate only those whose `isGroupChat` matches false?